# Cabecera con Empresa y Detalle de Filtros en Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

Necesito saber una forma de agregar una cabecera a los reportes en jasper que tenga los datos de página, filtros configurados y logo, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hemos agregado un subreporte configurable, pero no tiene la página o los datos de generación, si no que ocupa espacio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe una forma mejor de hacer esta cabecera?

Actualmente tengo 65 reportes y me gustaria poder agregarselo y modificarselo en caso de ser necesario

Saludos y Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar parámetros en el reporte, y a la vez enviarlas al subreporte, para que sea llenada de acuerdo a lo que le envíes.

Por ejemplo para la imágen, puedes enviarle un parámetro al reporte "padre" y en el subreporte en la opción **parameters**, agegar uno a uno los necesarios.

En la imágen podrías usar algo similar a ésto en "ImageExpression" **$P{RutaImagen}**, éste método lo he utilizado en reportes, desde una aplicación en Java.